# Better performance MetadaWorkspace or Reflection?

Tags: entity-framework-5, c#-5.0

Fellows,

What is the best option performance to get entity properties ? Querying objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems or iterating table.Getproperties by Reflection ?

Comment: Only the properties? - `GetItems`. The values also? - depends.

Comment: I've just got the tests and MetadataWorkspace is better !